# Android JNI: FindClass() cannot find my class

Tags: android, class, java-native-interface

I am trying to use FindClass on one of my Java file in Android, but it never finds the class.

I use the following code (C++):

```
jclass clsLocal = env->FindClass("com/device/client/HostConnection");
```

In Eclipse, in src, I have the package com.device.client and the file HostConnection.java in it.

It seems to me that the error has to do with the -classpath. I am not completely sure if that is the problem though. This is a cat of .classpath generated by Eclipse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

The directory src/ contains the directory com/, which contains device/, which contains client/:

```
rudys@rudys-N61Jq:~/workspace/DeviceClient/src/com/device/client$ ls
HostConnection.java  Main.java  ServerConnection.java  SettingsLayout.java
```

I tried to create a rule in the .classpath such as:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/com/device/client"/>
```

but Eclipse spots it as a problem (nested with src/), so I believe the path="src/" already takes care of all those subdirectories.

I am not sure what it is not working.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: I've realized that in my thread FindClass() doesn't work but it does in the native method, so it's not that line of code itself the problem but where I've put it. I am not sure why that is.

Comment: Have you found your problem? And what JNIEnv are you using?

Comment: The problem is fixed, I will make a new post. It was because I was calling this method at the wrong place, the classpath was fine.

Comment: Thus post your solution as answer and accept it to close the post ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was starting a new thread, and running the code in that thread.

I should have gotten the class inside the function from Java, and that works well.